# Have a class/object with a lot of properties, how do I automatically generate a table in edmx of Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, class

Surely this is out there (or maybe you just can't do this?).

I have a class in my project with a bunch of properties. I already have an edmx with two tables in it. How do I automatically make a third table for this new class. I don't want to manually add 40 properties to a new table.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this isn't a great answer, but I know the newer versions of EF (4+ I think) support "code first" entities.  I've never used this feature, but a quick google search for "Code First Entity Framework" may give you the answer you seek.

Edit: here's a link to Scott Gu's blog on the feature (which is where I read about it originally): http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: Yes, I was about to post a similar answer. Worth keeping in mind is that it's all or nothing: you cannot define two tables in an EDMX file, and the third in code. Either they all get put in the EDMX file, or they are all defined by classes in your project.

Comment: Thanks, hmm, I am reading a bunch about the code first - but really, I already have an edmx file and I added a class to the project and want to be able to store the new class object's info in my database. But to manually add all the properties seems stupid. There's no way to automatically make a table? maybe the answer lies in code first, but either it is very non intuitive or I just am not seeing it yet?   EDIT: okay so that answers that, thanks @hvd

Comment: There may be some third party tool that does what you need, but unfortunately I'm not familiar with any.  Good luck!